# Pyspark : Cumulative Sum with reset condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cumulative-sum

We have dataframe like below :

```
+------+--------------------+
| Flag |               value|
+------+--------------------+
|1     |5                   |
|1     |4                   |
|1     |3                   |
|1     |5                   |
|1     |6                   |
|1     |4                   |
|1     |7                   |
|1     |5                   |
|1     |2                   |
|1     |3                   |
|1     |2                   |
|1     |6                   |
|1     |9                   |      
+------+--------------------+
```

After normal cumsum we get this.

```
+------+--------------------+----------+
| Flag |               value|cumsum    |
+------+--------------------+----------+
|1     |5                   |5         |
|1     |4                   |9         |
|1     |3                   |12        |
|1     |5                   |17        |
|1     |6                   |23        |
|1     |4                   |27        |
|1     |7                   |34        |
|1     |5                   |39        |
|1     |2                   |41        |
|1     |3                   |44        |
|1     |2                   |46        |
|1     |6                   |52        |
|1     |9                   |61        |       
+------+--------------------+----------+
```

Now what we want is for cumsum to reset when specific condition is set for ex. when it crosses 20.

Below is expected output:

```
+------+--------------------+----------+---------+
| Flag |               value|cumsum    |expected |
+------+--------------------+----------+---------+
|1     |5                   |5         |5        |
|1     |4                   |9         |9        |
|1     |3                   |12        |12       |
|1     |5                   |17        |17       |
|1     |6                   |23        |23       |
|1     |4                   |27        |4        |  <-----reset 
|1     |7                   |34        |11       |
|1     |5                   |39        |16       |
|1     |2                   |41        |18       |
|1     |3                   |44        |21       |
|1     |2                   |46        |2        |  <-----reset
|1     |6                   |52        |8        |
|1     |9                   |61        |17       |         
+------+--------------------+----------+---------+
```

This is how we are calculating the cumulative sum.

```
win_counter = Window.partitionBy("flag")

df_partitioned = df_partitioned.withColumn('cumsum',F.sum(F.col('value')).over(win_counter))
```

Comment: Did you find the solution on your problem ? I'm looking for the exact same thing

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I've found to solve it without `udf`:

#### Dataframe

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (1, 5), (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 4),
  (1, 7), (1, 5), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 6), (1, 9)
], schema='Flag int, value int')

w = (Window
     .partitionBy('flag')
     .orderBy(f.monotonically_increasing_id())
     .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow))
df = df.withColumn('values', f.collect_list('value').over(w))

expr = "AGGREGATE(values, 0, (acc, el) -> IF(acc < 20, acc + el, el))"
df = df.select('Flag', 'value', f.expr(expr).alias('cumsum'))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

#### RDD

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (1, 5), (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 4),
  (1, 7), (1, 5), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 6), (1, 9)
], schema='Flag int, value int')

def cumsum_by_flag(rows):
  cumsum, reset = 0, False
  for row in rows:
    if reset:
      cumsum = row.value
      reset = False
    else:
      cumsum += row.value
      
    reset = cumsum > 20
    yield row.value, cumsum
    
    
def unpack(value):
  flag = value[0]
  value, cumsum = value[1]
  return flag, value, cumsum


rdd = df.rdd.keyBy(lambda row: row.Flag)
rdd = (rdd
       .groupByKey()
       .flatMapValues(cumsum_by_flag)
       .map(unpack))

df = rdd.toDF('Flag int, value int, cumsum int')
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+------+
|Flag|value|cumsum|
+----+-----+------+
|1   |5    |5     |
|1   |4    |9     |
|1   |3    |12    |
|1   |5    |17    |
|1   |6    |23    |
|1   |4    |4     |
|1   |7    |11    |
|1   |5    |16    |
|1   |2    |18    |
|1   |3    |21    |
|1   |2    |2     |
|1   |6    |8     |
|1   |9    |17    |
+----+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to do with `pandas_udf` here.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'flag':[1]*13,'id':range(13), 'value': [5,4,3,5,6,4,7,5,2,3,2,6,9]})
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
df = df.withColumn('cumsum', F.lit(math.inf))

@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def _calc_cumsum(pdf):
    pdf.sort_values(by=['id'], inplace=True, ascending=True)
    cumsums = []
    prev = None
    reset = False
    for v in pdf['value'].values:
        if prev is None:
            cumsums.append(v)
            prev = v
        else:
            prev = prev + v if not reset else v
            cumsums.append(prev)
            reset = True if prev >= 20 else False
            
    pdf['cumsum'] = cumsums
    return pdf

df = df.groupby('flag').apply(_calc_cumsum)
df.show()
```

the results:

```
+----+---+-----+------+
|flag| id|value|cumsum|
+----+---+-----+------+
|   1|  0|    5|   5.0|
|   1|  1|    4|   9.0|
|   1|  2|    3|  12.0|
|   1|  3|    5|  17.0|
|   1|  4|    6|  23.0|
|   1|  5|    4|   4.0|
|   1|  6|    7|  11.0|
|   1|  7|    5|  16.0|
|   1|  8|    2|  18.0|
|   1|  9|    3|  21.0|
|   1| 10|    2|   2.0|
|   1| 11|    6|   8.0|
|   1| 12|    9|  17.0|
+----+---+-----+------+
```