# Pyspark Group By Date Range

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by

I have a sample pyspark dataframe that can be created like this

```
sample_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', 1),
    ('2020-02-01', '2021-02-01', 1),
    ('2021-01-15', '2022-01-15', 2),
    ('2022-01-15', '2023-01-15', 2),
    ('2022-02-01', '2023-02-01', 3),
    ('2022-03-01', '2023-03-01', 3),
    ('2023-03-01', '2024-03-01', 4),
  ], ['item_date', 'max_window', 'expected_grouping_index'])
```

After sorting by `item_date`, I want to assume the first item starts a grouping. Any following item that is less than or equal to the first items `max_window` (which will always be the same number of days added to the `item_date` for the entire df, about 365 days in this example) will be given the same `grouping_index`.

If an item does not fall inside the grouping, it will start a new grouping and be given another arbitrary `grouping_index`. Then all following items will be assessed based on that items `max_window`. And so on.

The `grouping_index` is just a means goal, I eventually want to only keep the first row in each group.

How can I achieve this without a UDF or converting to a pandas df?

Comment: Can you please post the expected output as well?

Comment: There should be a column called `expected_grouping_index` in the sample df

Comment: You can use datediff to find differences between two dates. Then maintain a cumulative sum of the successive dates till the point it is 365 days and then reset the cumulative sum. 

https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-difference-between-two-dates-days-months-years/

Comment: @user238607 theoretically that sounds great! I'm not sure how to do the resetting part so that we're performing a datediff on the next groups initial item_date though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following answer as an inspiration to write the following code.
Basically, clever use of complex accumulator function allows the grouping index to be performed properly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64957835/3238085

```
import sys

from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)

sample_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', 1),
    ('2020-02-01', '2021-02-01', 1),
    ('2021-01-15', '2022-01-15', 2),
    ('2022-01-15', '2023-01-15', 2),
    ('2022-02-01', '2023-02-01', 3),
    ('2022-03-01', '2023-03-01', 3),
    ('2023-03-01', '2024-03-01', 4),
], ['item_date', 'max_window', 'expected_grouping_index'])

sample_df.show(100, truncate=False)

sample_df = sample_df.withColumn("item_date", col("item_date").cast("date"))

windowSpec = Window.orderBy("item_date")

sample_df = sample_df.withColumn("datedifference",
                                 datediff(col("item_date"), lag(col("item_date"), 1).over(windowSpec)))

w = (windowSpec.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow))
sample_df = sample_df.withColumn('datedifferencelist', F.collect_list('datedifference').over(w))

# expr = "AGGREGATE(datedifferencelist, (0,0), (acc, el) -> IF(acc[0] + el < 365, (acc[0] + el, acc[1]),  (el, acc[1]+1) ))"
# sample_df = sample_df.withColumn('cumsum', F.expr(expr))

initial_value = F.array(F.lit(0), F.lit(0))

sample_df = sample_df.withColumn('cumsum', aggregate("datedifferencelist", initial_value,
                                                     lambda acc, x:  F.when( ((acc.getItem(0) + x) <= 365), F.array(acc.getItem(0) + x, acc.getItem(1))).otherwise( F.array(F.lit(0), acc.getItem(1) + 1)   )    ))

sample_df = sample_df.withColumn('group_id', F.col('cumsum').getItem(1))

sample_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+----------+----------+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------+--------+
|item_date |max_window|expected_grouping_index|datedifference|datedifferencelist         |cumsum  |group_id|
+----------+----------+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------+--------+
|2020-01-01|2021-01-01|1                      |NULL          |[]                         |[0, 0]  |0       |
|2020-02-01|2021-02-01|1                      |31            |[31]                       |[31, 0] |0       |
|2021-01-15|2022-01-15|2                      |349           |[31, 349]                  |[0, 1]  |1       |
|2022-01-15|2023-01-15|2                      |365           |[31, 349, 365]             |[365, 1]|1       |
|2022-02-01|2023-02-01|3                      |17            |[31, 349, 365, 17]         |[0, 2]  |2       |
|2022-03-01|2023-03-01|3                      |28            |[31, 349, 365, 17, 28]     |[28, 2] |2       |
|2023-03-01|2024-03-01|4                      |365           |[31, 349, 365, 17, 28, 365]|[0, 3]  |3       |
+----------+----------+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------+--------+
```