# PySpark: count over a window with reset

Tags: python, pyspark, count, spark-window-function

I have a PySpark DataFrame which looks like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[
    (1, "GERMANY", "20230606", True),
    (2, "GERMANY", "20230620", False),
    (3, "GERMANY", "20230627", True),
    (4, "GERMANY", "20230705", True),
    (5, "GERMANY", "20230714", False),
    (6, "GERMANY", "20230715", True),
    ],
    schema=["ID", "COUNTRY", "DATE", "FLAG"]
)
df.show()
```

```
+---+-------+--------+-----+
| ID|COUNTRY|    DATE| FLAG|
+---+-------+--------+-----+
|  1|GERMANY|20230606| true|
|  2|GERMANY|20230620|false|
|  3|GERMANY|20230627| true|
|  4|GERMANY|20230705| true|
|  5|GERMANY|20230714|false|
|  6|GERMANY|20230715| true|
+---+-------+--------+-----+
```

The DataFrame has more countries. I want to create a new column `COUNT_WITH_RESET` following the logic:

- If `FLAG=False`, then `COUNT_WITH_RESET=0`.
- If `FLAG=True`, then `COUNT_WITH_RESET` should count the number of rows starting from the previous date where `FLAG=False` for that specific country.

This should be the output for the example above.

```
+---+-------+--------+-----+----------------+
| ID|COUNTRY|    DATE| FLAG|COUNT_WITH_RESET|
+---+-------+--------+-----+----------------+
|  1|GERMANY|20230606| true|               1|
|  2|GERMANY|20230620|false|               0|
|  3|GERMANY|20230627| true|               1|
|  4|GERMANY|20230705| true|               2|
|  5|GERMANY|20230714|false|               0|
|  6|GERMANY|20230715| true|               1|
+---+-------+--------+-----+----------------+
```

I have tried with `row_number()` over a window but I can't manage to reset the count. I have also tried with `.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)`. Here's my approach:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

window_reset = Window.partitionBy("COUNTRY").orderBy("DATE")

df_with_reset = (
    df
    .withColumn("COUNT_WITH_RESET", F.when(~F.col("FLAG"), 0)
                .otherwise(F.row_number().over(window_reset)))
)

df_with_reset.show()
```

```
+---+-------+--------+-----+----------------+
| ID|COUNTRY|    DATE| FLAG|COUNT_WITH_RESET|
+---+-------+--------+-----+----------------+
|  1|GERMANY|20230606| true|               1|
|  2|GERMANY|20230620|false|               0|
|  3|GERMANY|20230627| true|               3|
|  4|GERMANY|20230705| true|               4|
|  5|GERMANY|20230714|false|               0|
|  6|GERMANY|20230715| true|               6|
+---+-------+--------+-----+----------------+
```

This is obviously wrong as my window is partitioning only by country, but am I on the right track? Is there a specific built-in function in PySpark to achieve this? Do I need a UDF? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition the dataframe by `COUNTRY` then calculate the cumulative sum over the inverted `FLAG` column to assign group numbers in order to distinguish between different `blocks` of rows which start with `false`

```
W1 = Window.partitionBy('COUNTRY').orderBy('DATE')
df1 = df.withColumn('blocks', F.sum((~F.col('FLAG')).cast('long')).over(W1))

df1.show()
# +---+-------+--------+-----+------+
# | ID|COUNTRY|    DATE| FLAG|blocks|
# +---+-------+--------+-----+------+
# |  1|GERMANY|20230606| true|     0|
# |  2|GERMANY|20230620|false|     1|
# |  3|GERMANY|20230627| true|     1|
# |  4|GERMANY|20230705| true|     1|
# |  5|GERMANY|20230714|false|     2|
# |  6|GERMANY|20230715| true|     2|
# +---+-------+--------+-----+------+
```

Partition the dataframe by `COUNTRY` along with `blocks` then calculate row number over the ordered partition to create sequential counter

```
W2 = Window.partitionBy('COUNTRY', 'blocks').orderBy('DATE')
df1 = df1.withColumn('COUNT_WITH_RESET', F.row_number().over(W2) - 1)


df1.show()
# +---+-------+--------+-----+------+----------------+
# | ID|COUNTRY|    DATE| FLAG|blocks|COUNT_WITH_RESET|
# +---+-------+--------+-----+------+----------------+
# |  1|GERMANY|20230606| true|     0|               0|
# |  2|GERMANY|20230620|false|     1|               0|
# |  3|GERMANY|20230627| true|     1|               1|
# |  4|GERMANY|20230705| true|     1|               2|
# |  5|GERMANY|20230714|false|     2|               0|
# |  6|GERMANY|20230715| true|     2|               1|
# +---+-------+--------+-----+------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, that method to create the different blocks is clever.

Answer (score 1):

I modified my answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78056548/3238085
to this problem setup.

```
import sys

from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)

sample_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    data=[
        (1, "GERMANY", "20230606", True),
        (2, "GERMANY", "20230620", False),
        (3, "GERMANY", "20230627", True),
        (4, "GERMANY", "20230705", True),
        (5, "GERMANY", "20230714", False),
        (6, "GERMANY", "20230715", True),
    ],
    schema=["ID", "COUNTRY", "DATE", "FLAG"]
)

sample_df.show(100, truncate=False)

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("COUNTRY").orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
sample_df = sample_df.withColumn('FLAGLIST', F.collect_list('FLAG').over(windowSpec))

initial_value = F.lit(0)

sample_df = sample_df.withColumn('COUNT_WITH_RESET', aggregate("FLAGLIST", initial_value,
                                                               lambda acc, x:  F.when( x == True,  acc + 1).otherwise(0)))

sample_df.show(truncate=False)
```

OUTPUT :

```
+---+-------+--------+-----+
|ID |COUNTRY|DATE    |FLAG |
+---+-------+--------+-----+
|1  |GERMANY|20230606|true |
|2  |GERMANY|20230620|false|
|3  |GERMANY|20230627|true |
|4  |GERMANY|20230705|true |
|5  |GERMANY|20230714|false|
|6  |GERMANY|20230715|true |
+---+-------+--------+-----+

+---+-------+--------+-----+--------------------------------------+----------------+
|ID |COUNTRY|DATE    |FLAG |FLAGLIST                              |COUNT_WITH_RESET|
+---+-------+--------+-----+--------------------------------------+----------------+
|1  |GERMANY|20230606|true |[true]                                |1               |
|2  |GERMANY|20230620|false|[true, false]                         |0               |
|3  |GERMANY|20230627|true |[true, false, true]                   |1               |
|4  |GERMANY|20230705|true |[true, false, true, true]             |2               |
|5  |GERMANY|20230714|false|[true, false, true, true, false]      |0               |
|6  |GERMANY|20230715|true |[true, false, true, true, false, true]|1               |
+---+-------+--------+-----+--------------------------------------+----------------+
```